# How to get only links to other articles in Wikipedia article using Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup, wikipedia

I'd like to create graph using links of articles in wikipedia. So I need to extract hyperlinks from parent-page to next nodes-articles.

How can I do it using Jsoup, for example? My problem is that I know how to extract all links but not only needed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Show us the code that you have for extartcting all the links, and define what is your "needed links".

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Document doc =  Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston").timeout(5000).get();

Element intro = doc.body().select("p").first();
while (intro.tagName().equals("p")) {
    //here you will get an Elements object which you can
    //iterate through to get the links in the intro
    System.out.println(intro.select("a"));
    intro = intro.nextElementSibling();
}

for (Element h2 : doc.body().select("h2")) {
    if(h2.select("span").size() == 2) {
        if (h2.select("span").get(1).text().equals("Geography")) {
            Element nextsib = h2.nextElementSibling();
            while (nextsib != null) {
                if (nextsib.tagName().equals("p")) {
                    //here you will get an Elements object which you
                    //can iterate through to get the links in the 
                    //geography section
                    System.out.println(nextsib.select("a"));
                    nextsib = nextsib.nextElementSibling();
                } else if (nextsib.tagName().equals("h2")) {
                    nextsib = null;
                } else {
                    nextsib = nextsib.nextElementSibling();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar for a personal project of mine.

See:

```
    try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.wikipedia.org/").get();
            links = doc.select("a");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String[] temp = new String[100]; //Should use ArrayList for this due to unknown number of URLS, I'm just giving an example
        if (links != null) {
            for(Element link : links){
                String temp = link.attr("href");
            }
        }
```

`doc.select("a")` selects all tags with `<a ..... />` on the page.

`link.attr("href")` gets URL to articles inside those tags.

Consider adding a `isValidLink` function inside the `for` loop to make sure the Wikipedia link you are grabbing is, in fact, an article and not just a random link. For my project, my `isValidLink` was as follows:

```
private boolean isValidURL(String temp){
        if(temp.contains("thestar.com") && temp.length() > 75 && (temp.contains("/news/") || temp.contains("/business/") || temp.contains("/sports/") || temp.contains("/entertainment/") || temp.contains("/life/"))){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Hope that helps out a bit